# java swing button does not repaint properly after dialog closed

Tags: java, swing, awt, modal-dialog, repaint

I have a JButton and pressing it opens a modal dialog. When I close the dialog, the button still look like it is still in a pressed state until I move the mouse. I think this is happening because the JDialog is opened on top of an AWT component (it's a 3rd party component  that uses an AWT Canvas, and I can't change that). If I open the dialog and close it over a swing component, then it works properly.

I've tried adding a window listener to the dialog and repainting the entire frame (using repaint and paintImmediately) when the dialog closes, but this doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here is an SSCCE example. Press the button and then close the dialog. Notice the focus border is still around the button until moving the mouse over the green section.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DialogExample
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        final JFrame jf = new JFrame("AWT/Swing Dialog Test");
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton button = new JButton("show dialog");
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
        };
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        button.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                JDialog dlg = new JDialog(jf,"modal");
                dlg.add(new JLabel("hello"));
                dlg.setModal(true);
                dlg.pack();
                dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(canvas);
                dlg.setVisible(true);
            }            
        });
        button.setText("press me");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);        
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(button);
        jf.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jf.add(canvas, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Comment: *"I think this is happening because the JDialog is opened on top of an AWT component"* Why not try to reproduce it in an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: I haven't used AWT components in a long, long time. All I remember is that you get in trouble when you mix it with Swing. But I would suggest to bring an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Guillaume  That is true, though it usually only applies to Swing floating elements like the drop-down of a `JComboBox` or a tool-tip.  I've never known it to happen when AWT components are in one window and Swing in another.  Java 7 apparently offers a flag that is intended to allow AWT & Swing components to be mixed freely.

Comment: @AndrewThompson OK, good to know. Although, I am not sure I will be using AWT any time soon. But still, my knowledge improved. Thanks

Comment: While I didn't want to use AWT, it's a JOGL component which seems to work better using the AWT version. I'm going to work on isolating the example to post. Thanks.

Comment: @Guillaume *"not sure I will be using AWT any time soon"* I'm already dreading the expected flood of mixtures of Swing with the AWT canvas that might be produced by the new Java 7 flag.  ;)

Comment: Alright, so something else seems to be going on because I'm having a difficult time reproducing...will post back once I have something else to go on.

Comment: Ok, I have posted the example.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with your code. :( The button seems to be restored to its normal color after the dialog closes. I'm using Java 1.6 on a Windows 7 64 bit computer.

Comment: Is the dialog opened fully over the red area? There's just a slight border that seems to be there after the dialog is closed (but it must be closed over the red area entirely). I am also running Win 7 64bit

Comment: I can reproduce it with Metal L&F, but not Nimbus, CDE or Aqua (Mac Os X default). You might try setting the L&F explicitly. See also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). +1 for sscce.

Comment: Oracle-Java 1.6 on Linux, 32-bit: Everything fine.

Comment: We're targeting windows mostly so I set it to the Windows L&F and the problem exists there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an expedient, you can clear the rollover state when the dialog returns in `actionPerformed()`:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JDialog dlg = new JDialog(jf, "modal");
    dlg.add(new JLabel("hello"));
    dlg.setModal(true);
    dlg.pack();
    dlg.setLocationRelativeTo(canvas);
    dlg.setVisible(true);
    button.getModel().setRollover(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and post back on the results.